# Routing table after connecting to VPN

Tags: vpn, routing

I have some questions about what happens to routing table of my system and my router after I connect to a VPN server.

Let me explain the scenario first. We are three devices in our local area network: me (192.168.1.3), my brother ( 192.168.1.4 ) and router (192.168.1.1).

There is a camera(192.168.1.6) in another country which has a webserver allowing people to access it. I make a VPN connection to that LAN via this imaginary IP address (34.34.34.34), and then connect to 192.168.1.6 (camera).

1- As I joined that LAN via VPN, can I still ping my brother's computer?

2- what happens to my computer's routing table? My guess is there a record which says EVERY IP address should go to default gateway - my router- (because eventually all requests should be go to that LAN)

3- Does it somehow affect my router's routing table?

I mostly wanted to know which routes are adding to routing tables of my computer and my router that take me from my computer to the camera.

Comment: Are you asking about a specific VPN system that you're actually using, or are you asking about VPNs in general?

Comment: @user1686 VPNs in general. I just don't get the idea of how this tunnel leads my requests from my computer to the camera. what are the routes that make this tunnel working ?